# jquery remove issue in IE, canvas tag

Tags: jquery, drawing, canvas

I am creating a line in canvas tag using jquery drawing library. After the line drawn the

```
<div id="cool"><canvas id="canid"></canvas></div>
```

Then on click the below code executed.

```
$('#canid').remove();
```

What happens in IE after removing,  dom with canvas end tag and also line is not removed.

Please help me out!.

Comment: When you're saying it doesn't work in IE, you'll have to be more specific (this goes for any question IE related).  IE 6, 7, 8 and 9 vary a *great* deal, which ones are you trying to support?

Comment: IE doesn't support any tags it doesn't know. It doesn't even add them to the DOM, so they can't be "removed".

Comment: You need to use explorer canvas for support in IE. then it will become supported. http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/
It will translate your canvas code into VML that ie understands

Comment: @RoToTa Line is drawing in the IE. IE takes in the tag canavas. Problem when i am removing it.

Answer (score 2):

`<canvas>` isn't supported natively by Internet Explorer - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element

Try looking into VML tags and the aforementioned [ExCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. jquery drawing library is producing the dot(1 x 1) pixel div dot, to form it has lines. I can able to found a lots of dive below the canvas tag. So canvas tag is dummy and pixel div(s) are creating the line. I just removed the pixel links with class i mentioned to remove the line. It work great.